# Keep only same names for two text files?

Tags: r

I have two text files
File 1

```
File1=read.table("C:\\file1.txt", sep="")
Value   name
  0.2    sam
  0.4  david
  3    david
  7    nicola
```

File 2

```
File2=read.table("C:\\file2.txt", sep="")
Value   name
  0.8 nicola
  0.9  david
```

Keep only rows where names exist in both files. For instance, desired outputs:

File 1

```
Value   name
  7  nicola
```

File 2

```
Value   name
  0.8  nicola
```

Note that Dived was removed in my desired output because I have 2 David in file 1 and 1 David in File 2. sam was removed because we do not have it in file2

Comment: I know that your code is only an example; nevertheless: **never** use absolute paths in your scripts. The resulting code is completely unportable, and this is actually a huge problem in real-word code.

Comment: You could get both values simultaneously by a simple merge such as `merge(File1, File2, by = "name")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `%in%`

```
df1[df1$name %in% df2$name,]
#  Value  name
#2   0.4 david
df2[df2$name %in% df1$name,]
#  Value  name
#2   0.9 david
```

Comment: @temor Then, you should have showed that in the example.  We can't guess what is in your original file.

Comment: @temor Based on the new update, the question doesn't seem to be duplicate.  But, as it is already tagged as dupe, can you post this as a new question.

Comment: @temor I answered the question you posted.  So, I don't have to remove the answer.  If it is not the question you have, you should post a new question.